# Fetch Json from mysql database using php

Tags: php, mysql

The code i have fetches values less than 255, but it does not return if the values in the column are more than 255.

```
<?php
    include 'dbconfig.php';
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    if($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    } 
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM news ORDER BY id DESC";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
    if($result->num_rows >0){
        while($row[] = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            $tem = $row;
            $json = json_encode($tem); 
        }
    }else {
        echo "0 results";
    }
    echo $json;
    $conn->close();
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to:

```
if($result->num_rows >0){
    $json=[];
    while(($row = $result->fetch_assoc())) {
        $json[] = $row;
    }
    echo json_encode($json);
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
```

Comment: displays nothing, but when i reduce the characters in the table column to around 10, it returns the json, but when i add more, it does not return

Comment: Please attach a link to the code with a dump of your table.